# Finding one row from pivot table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables called `conversations` and `users` they are bound with the pivot table `conversation_user` which contains a `user_id` and a `conversation_id` column.

```
| conversation_id | user_id |
|-----------------|---------|
|               1 |       1 |
|               1 |       2 |
|               2 |       1 |
|               2 |       2 |
|               2 |       3 |
```

I want to send the database some user ids and retrieve the conversation they are in together.

For example:

When I send `1` and `2` i must receive the conversation_id `1`, when I send `1`, `2` and `3` i must receive the conversation_id `2`.

How may I write a such query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT conversation_id 
FROM tab                     -- subquery/temp table/whatever
GROUP BY conversation_id 
HAVING SUM(user_id = 1) > 0
   AND SUM(user_id = 2) > 0
   AND SUM(user_id = 3) > 0
   AND SUM(user_id NOT IN (1,2,3)) = 0
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d1e9/14/0)**</kbd>

For 1 and 2:

```
SELECT conversation_id 
FROM tab
GROUP BY conversation_id 
HAVING SUM(user_id = 1) > 0
   AND SUM(user_id = 2) > 0
   AND SUM(user_id NOT IN (1,2)) = 0
```

Comment: **Thank you, a lot!**

Answer (score 0):

Group_concat can be used to retrieve results as per your requirement. You can change the having clause condition accordingly:try this let me know

```
SELECT conversion_id 
FROM (
    SELECT 
    conversion_id, 
    group_concat(user_id, ',')
    FROM conversions
    HAVING group_concat(user_id, ',') = '1,2,3' 
    GROUP BY conversion_id
)
```